# ToolStripMenuItem.CheckState

Tags: c#, winforms

Вообще сбрасывается значение ToolStripMenuItem.CheckState в false.

При старте программы даю значение

```
ProgramToolStripMenuItem.Checked = true;
```

После вижу что на кнопке галочка стоит.
Теперь же хочу при нажатии на кнопку сбросить это значение если оно true или же поставить если оно false.

```
if (ProgramToolStripMenuItem.Checked==false)
            {
                ProgramToolStripMenuItem.Checked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ProgramToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
            }
```

Но я прохожу по частям код, но при этом значение всегда false, а галочка стоит. Хотя я в начале поставил значение true. То есть оно сбрасывается само почему-то.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте свойство `ToolStripMenuItem.CheckOnClick` ([источник](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem.checkonclick?view=netcore-3.0)). Необходимо установить его значение как `true`. Тогда каждый клик по кнопке будет инвертировать текущее значение. В чем и заключается ваша задача. Никаких дополнительных условий `if-else` делать не нужно.

Comment: Спасибо большое!)